# How to make bottom menu with text and one button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a bottom menu which should look like on the screenshot. Can you help me with it? I searched for it and find only BottomAppBar but i didn't find how can i put text in it and put button.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/I2TnlkM]

Comment: Hi, is this menu sticky or something will be appear and dismiss (after a while or by click on button)?

Comment: @RezaAbedi hey. It's should be permanent. It should disappear only if user will click "yes"

Comment: I just added an answer with custom Snackbar view and indefinite time for showing Snackbar to dismiss only by user action. you can copy and paste code to see results.

Comment: @RezaAbedi thank you! I'm just accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your attached image I found out you need to use `Snackbar` or `BottomSheet`, but personally, I prefer to use `Snackbar` in this case.
Below is code for `custom_snackbar.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FF03DAC5"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is message or question"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <!--this view separates between button and the message-->
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gotoWebsiteButton"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Action Button"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is code for showing `Snackbar` in `java` file:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
        , "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

// inflate the custom_snackbar_view created previously
View customSnackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, null);

// set the background of the default snackbar as transparent
snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

// now change the layout of the snackbar
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

// set padding of the all corners as 0
snackbarLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

// register the button from the custom_snackbar_view layout file
Button bGotoWebsite = customSnackView.findViewById(R.id.gotoWebsiteButton);

// now handle the same button with onClickListener
bGotoWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "do some thing except dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        snackbar.dismiss();
    }
});

// add the custom snack bar layout to snackbar layout
snackbarLayout.addView(customSnackView, 0);

snackbar.show();
```

alse here is `Kotlin` language

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
            findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )

// inflate the custom_snackbar_view created previously
val customSnackView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, null)

// set the background of the default snackbar as transparent
snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

// now change the layout of the snackbar
val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as SnackbarLayout

// set padding of the all corners as 0
snackbarLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)

// register the button from the custom_snackbar_view layout file
val bGotoWebsite = customSnackView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.gotoWebsiteButton)

// now handle the same button with onClickListener
bGotoWebsite.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "do some thing except dismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            snackbar.dismiss()
        }

// add the custom snack bar layout to snackbar layout
snackbarLayout.addView(customSnackView, 0)
snackbar.show()
```

You can see the result view in the attached image and you can customize the `Snackbar` view.
[image]

I wish you enjoy the answer.

Comment: can you help me to make it on Kotlin?

Comment: Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();

Comment: I don't know how to make this line in Kotlin :(

Comment: This is in Kotlin:`val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as SnackbarLayout`

Comment: I have problem. IDE see problem in my line: 'snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)'

Comment: It says "snackbar has not been initialized"

Comment: You should have line like this in top lines`val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
            findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)`

Comment: I just added the whole Kotlin code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working. Looks like i'm really bad rn in Android development :( It's like 3 months of self-education for me right now

Comment: It's going to be easy if you learn more. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! Just curious is it possible to make this snackbar disappear by swiping it? :/

Comment: i have one more thing. Can you please tell how can i save this Snackbar in SharedPreferences? I mean visibility of this snackbar will be already enough. Maybe we can save bool variable of visibility of this snackbar?

Comment: You can use `snackbar.isShown`

Comment: so i can just save in preferences variable which tracking status of this. got it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

As in the image you attach I think you need a snackbar or custom snackbar not menu or appbar so if you want a custom snackbar you can follow the code in this example.

you can get the Snackbar's View. The getView function returns the Snackbar.SnackbarLayout, which is a horizontal LinearLayout object whose children are a TextView and a Button. To add your own View to the Snackbar, you just need to hide the TextView, and add your View to the Snackbar.SnackbarLayout.

```
 // Create the Snackbar
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(containerLayout, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
// Get the Snackbar's layout view
Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
// Hide the text
TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Inflate our custom view
View snackView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
// Configure the view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
TextView textViewTop = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.text);
textViewTop.setText(text);
textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

//If the view is not covering the whole snackbar layout, add this line
layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

// Add the view to the Snackbar's layout
layout.addView(snackView, 0);
// Show the Snackbar
snackbar.show();
```